# How to write regex pattern to match AAAA00000000-0000?

Tags: regex

I need a regex to match a string in any of these formats:

1. "AAAA00000000"
2. "AAAA00000000-0000"
3. "0000000000"

I've got the first and third pattern right, this is what I came up with

```
^(([a-zA-Z]{4}[0-9]{8})|([0-9]{10}))$
```

I can't get that working to include the second pattern.

Comment: Where does the `[0-9]{10}` come from? Should `0000000000` be matched too (without leading letters)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
^[a-zA-Z]{4}[0-9]{8}(-[0-9]{4})?$
```

That is, `XXXXnnnnnnnn` and an *optional* `-nnnn` part.

- `XXXXnnnnnnnn`
- `XXXXnnnnnnnn-nnnn`

You can leave out the outermost parenthesis as this group equals the entire match (capturing group 0).

**EDIT**
Update to match `nnnnnnnnnn`, too:

```
^[0-9]{10}|[a-zA-Z]{4}[0-9]{8}(-[0-9]{4})?$
```

Matches:

- `nnnnnnnnnn`
- `XXXXnnnnnnnn`
- `XXXXnnnnnnnn-nnnn`

**EDIT #2**
In response to comment, this is the shortest / most readable I'm able to cook up:

```
^[0-9]{10}|[a-zA-Z]{4}[0-9]{8}(-[0-9]{4}|)$
```

Same characteristics as immediately above.

Comment: Works for the XXXXnnnnnnnn-nnnn and nnnnnnnnnn patterns, fails on XXXXnnnnnnnn

Comment: @dombenoit What language are you using. I've tested on http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html and it works as *I* intend.

Comment: @dombenoit I find it hard to believe that the `?` operator should not be supported, but try replacing it with `{0,1}`... Alternatively, does `^([0-9]{10}|[a-zA-Z]{4}[0-9]{8}-[0-9]{4}|[a-zA-Z]{4}[0-9]{8})$` work?

Comment: @jensgram Going from your updated solution, I modified it like so : "^[a-zA-Z]{4}[0-9]{8}|([a-zA-Z]{4}[0-9]{8}(-[0-9]{4})|[0-9]{10})?$" and that seems to be doing exactly what I need.

Comment: @dombenoit In that case you should be able to get this to work, too: `^[0-9]{10}|[a-zA-Z]{4}[0-9]{8}(-[0-9]{4}|)$` ... I *guess* :)

Comment: @jensgram I ended up going with your last suggestion, since mine also matched XXXXnnnnnnnn-XXXX. Thank you very much sir!

Comment: @dombenoit You're welcome. Edited my answer to reflect final, working solution.

Answer (score 0):

^\w{4}\d{8}(-\d{4})?$

Fixed a typo

Comment: Doesnt work. Think you missed a closing } on your optional pattern

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the "-" of the second format...

Answer (score 0):

```
^[a-zA-Z]{4}([0-9]{8}|[0-9]{8}\-[0-9]{4})$
```